# The present age of a man is twice that of his son. Eight years hence, there ages will be in the ratio 7:4. Find their present ages.

Tags: logic

I have a little problem with solving this question.I have searched on many websites but could not find an answer.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the man's age is $2x$ and the son's age is $x$.
Now 8 years later their ratio is $(2x+8)/(x+8) = 7/4)$
Now solve it. The answer is 24 years son and 48 years father.

Answer (score 1):

If present age of man and son is x and y years respectively.
Then by first condition,

```
 x=2y   which gives x-2y=0
```

And by second condition,

```
 (x+8)/(y+8)=7/4   which gives  4x-7y=24
```

Hence after solving above two equations,

x=48 and y=24

which are present ages of man and son resp.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

Let $m, s$, be the present ages of man and son in years.

1) $m=2s$.

2)In  $8$ years from now:

The man will have an age :$m+8$; the son: $s+8$.

$\dfrac{m+8}{s+8} =\dfrac{7}{4}.$

$4(m+8) =7 (s+8);$

$4m +32 = 7s +56.$

Combining 1) and 2):

$s = 24$;  $m=48.$